# How to update other properties of an object if one property changes?

Tags: javascript

My state object:

```
var obj = {
  propA: valA,
  propB: valB,
  propC: valC, // Percentage
}
```

I pass a parameter *type* to `updateObj({ type: A })`. Based on the obj prop that is updated manually, type can be one of `A, B or C`

Whenever one of `propA, propB or propC` is updated, other two sibling properties should also get updated.

I use the following logic to achieve the result,

```
function updateObj({type, val, modifierA, modifierB}) {
  obj.propA = (function() {
    if (type === 'B') return (val / modifierA) * modifierB;
    if (type === 'C') return (val / modifierA) * 100;
    return val
  })();
  obj.propB = (function() {
    if (type === 'A') return (val / modifierB) * modifierA;
    if (type === 'C') return (val / modifierB) * 100;
    return val
  })();
  obj.propC = (function() {
    if (type === 'A') return (val / 100) * modifierA;
    if (type === 'B') return (val / 100) * modifierB;
    return val
  })();
}
```

I want that based on `type`, other two siblings should get updated without having to specify them specifically.

Is there a way to do it less verbosely in a way that it can be reusable?

---

**EDIT**

---

I have table with input fields and some fixed values:

Columns of the table;

*A(fixed Value)* | *B(fixed Value)* | *FieldA* | *FieldB* | *FieldC*

where, FieldA, FieldB and FieldC(Percentage) contain HTML `input` Fields.

There are many rows in this table, and each one has a state object of the form:

My state object:

```
var obj = {
  propA: valA,
  propB: valB,
  propC: valC, // Percentage
}
```

My final state object is an Object of objects:

```
{
  row1: {
    propA: valA,
    propB: valB,
    propC: valC, // Percentage
  },
  row2: {
    propA: valA,
    propB: valB,
    propC: valC, // Percentage
  }
  //.....//
}
```

---

Now when the user enters a value in any one the input fields, other two fields in the same row should also be updated.

For eg, If *A(fixed value)* is 1000, *B(fixed value)* is 800 and the user enters 600 in *FieldA*. The fields should be updated with the logic:

*FieldA*: 1000

*FieldB*: (600 / 1000) * 800

*FiledC*: (600 / 1000) * 100

Comment: So you're basically asking help to find a less verbose version of what you already have?

Comment: Your logic seems really complex.

Comment: there is no way to achieve that in any less verbose way in javascript (or similar programming languages), answers below are also verbose just variations on what you already have

Comment: @NikosM. sure there is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to abstract is the inversion of operations:
For example a multiplication can be reversed with a division:

```
 // Every operation got a "run" function which does the operation and an "invert" function that returns the inversed operation
 const add = value => ({ 
   run(acc) { return acc + value; },
   invert() { return add(-value); }
 });

 const multiply = value => ({
  run(acc) { return acc * value; },
  invert() { return multiply(1 / value); }
 });

 // An operation that does nothing, called "identity" in the functional world
 const identity = ({ run(acc) { return acc; }, invert() { return identity; } });

// combines multiple operations, e.g. combine(add(1), multiply(2)) is (acc + 1) * 2 and can be inversed to acc / 2 + 1
const combine = (...ops) => ({
  op(acc) { return ops.reduce((acc, op) => op(acc), acc); },
  invert() { return combine(...[...ops].reverse().map(it => it.invert())); }
});
```

Now to build up the object from one of the values, you could represent the properties as a tree (B is calculated from A, C from B), then when you get a value, go the tree up by inverting the operation till you reach the root, then go down all paths to get all values:

```
 // Represents an operation node in the tree
 const op = (key, op, ...sub) => ({ key, op, sub });

 // The upmost operation
 const tree = (key, ...sub) => op(key, identity, ...sub); 

 // Generates the resulting object based on the tree
 const fromRoot = (root, value, result = {}) => {
   result[root.key] = value;
   for(const child of root.sub) 
     fromRoot(child, child.op.run(value), result);
   return result;
 };

// like "undefined", just that it can be distinguished from "undefined" as an operation might return that
const nothing = Symbol("nothing");

// Calculates the base value from one of the trees nodes
const getBase = (tree, key, value) => {
  if(tree.key === key)
    return tree.op.invert().run(value);

 for(const child of tree.sub) {
    const res = getBase(child, key, value);
    if(res === nothing) continue;
    return tree.op.invert().run(res);
 }

 return nothing;
};
```

Now I wrote some code, but at the end it allows you to write your operations like:

```
 const stuff = tree("A",
   op("B", multiply(10), // B = A * 10
     op("C", add(10)) // C = B + 10
   ),
   op("D", combine(add(10), multiply(10))) // D = (A + 10) * 10
);
```

To then insert a value, use the utilities from above:

```
 const result = fromRoot(stuff, getBase(stuff, "C", 20));
 console.log(result); // { A: 1, B: 10, C: 20, D: 110 }
```

Yes, all that works:

```js
// TESTCASES:

setTimeout(() => {
    const stuff = tree("A",
       op("B", multiply(10), // B = A * 10
         op("C", add(10)) // C = B + 10
       ),
       op("D", combine(add(10), multiply(10))) // D = (A + 10) * 10
    );
    
    // No matter which value you know, you will get back the same object
    const a = fromRoot(stuff, getBase(stuff, "A", 1));
    const b = fromRoot(stuff, getBase(stuff, "B", 10));
    const c = fromRoot(stuff, getBase(stuff, "C", 20));
    const d = fromRoot(stuff, getBase(stuff, "D", 110));
    console.log("a", a, "b", b, "c", c, "d", d);
});

// CODE FROM ABOVE:
const add = value => ({ 
   run(acc) { return acc + value; },
   invert() { return add(-value); }
});

const multiply = value => ({
   run(acc) { return acc * value; },
   invert() { return multiply(1 / value); }
});

const identity = ({ run(acc) { return acc; }, invert() { return identity; } });

// combines multiple operations, e.g. combine(add(1), multiply(2)) is (acc + 1) * 2 and can be inversed to acc / 2 + 1
const combine = (...ops) => ({
  run(acc) { return ops.reduce((acc, op) => op.run(acc), acc); },
  invert() { return combine(...[...ops].reverse().map(it => it.invert())); }
});

// Represents an operation node in the tree
const op = (key, op, ...sub) => ({ key, op, sub });
const tree = (key, ...sub) => op(key, identity, ...sub); 

// Generates the resulting object based on the tree
const fromRoot = (root, value, result = {}) => {
   result[root.key] = value;
   for(const child of root.sub) 
     fromRoot(child, child.op.run(value), result);
   return result;
};

// like "undefined", just that it can be distinguished from "undefined" as an operation might return that
const nothing = Symbol("nothing");

// Calculates the base value from one of the trees nodes
const getBase = (tree, key, value) => {
   if(tree.key === key)
     return tree.op.invert().run(value);

   for(const child of tree.sub) {
      const res = getBase(child, key, value);
      if(res === nothing) continue;
      return tree.op.invert().run(res);
   }

   return nothing;
};
```

Comment: Interesting approach, however, it's a bit overkill.

Comment: @ChrisTapay Well  For one object yes, but imagine more complicated relationships, then this will get quite useful (and the abstraction will be benefitial). If you find it interesting, feel free to upvote :) (that's what I usually do ... )

Comment: I appreciate functional programming and the answer uses it in correct and interesting ways but it is even more verbose than the original question

Comment: @NikosM. if you move the code I've written into a library, add it as an external dependency, you end up at 10 lines of code :)

Comment: Sure this would be the choice for more complex operations but if taken at face value the original question is only about these 3 properties

Comment: Sure thing @jonaswilms. Check my answer, I tried to stick to question scope: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726201/7630248

Comment: @JonasWilms, I have been trying to wrap my head around the solution that you provided, running it through debugger. I haven't been able to change my solution to use your approach.
In question, I already had the state object, to which I am making updates based on the field that changed.  `propA, propB and propC` are always updated. Your solution seems like it generates the relationship between sibling property on the fly.
It would be really helpful if you could provide a diagrammatic representation of the solution and an explanation to why you chose this way of implementation?

Comment: @harshvardhanSharma what are `propA`, `propB` and `propC` and what are `modifierA` and `modifierB` ? I chose this implementation as a tree, as you can represent every possible relationships of data as a tree. Then youncan always go up to the root from every node, and from there you can generate all possible values. In your case it'll be something like `tree("propA", op("propB", multiply(modifierA / modifierB), op("propC", multiply(100)))`

Comment: @JonasWilms, I appended an edit to the question. It explains my requirement

Comment: @JonasWilms In my case: `tree('propA', op('propB', multiply((1 / initialA) * initialB), op('propC', multiply((1/initialA) * 100))))`. Ingenious approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the logic that generates new values for each field, from the logic that updates the fields:

```js
const obj = {
  propA: 1,
  propB: 2,
  propC: 3,
}

const getNewValues = (val, modifierA, modifierB) => ({
  propA: {
    A: val,
    B: val / modifierA * modifierB,
    C: val / modifierA * 100
  },
  propB: {
    A: val / modifierB * modifierA,
    B: val,
    C: val / modifierB * 100
  },
  propC: {
    A: val / 100 * modifierA,
    B: val / 100 * modifierB,
    C: val
  }
});

function updateObj({ type, val, modifierA, modifierB }) {
  const newValues = getNewValues(val, modifierA, modifierB);
  Object.keys(newValues).forEach(prop => obj[prop] = newValues[prop][type]);
}

updateObj({ type: 'A', val: 10, modifierA: 1, modifierB: 1 });

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take an object with the values.

```
function updateObj({ type, val, modifierA, modifierB }) {
    var valueA = {
            A: val,
            B: val * modifierB / modifierA,
            C: val * 100 / modifierA
        },
        valueB = {
            A: val * modifierB / modifierA,
            B: val,
            C: val * 100 / modifierA
        },
        valueC = {
            A: val * modifierA / 100,
            B: val * modifierB / 100,
            C: val
        };

    obj.propA = valueA[type];
    obj.propB = valueB[type];
    obj.propC = valueC[type];
}
```

If you like to make the calculation at the time where the assignment happens, you could return a function, instead of values.

```
function updateObj({ type, val, modifierA, modifierB }) {
    var valueA = {
            A: () => val,
            B: () => val * modifierB / modifierA,
            C: () => val * 100 / modifierA
        },
        valueB = {
            A: () => val * modifierB / modifierA,
            B: () => val,
            C: () => val * 100 / modifierA
        },
        valueC = {
            A: () => val * modifierA / 100,
            B: () => val * modifierB / 100,
            C: () => val
        };

    obj.propA = valueA[type]();
    obj.propB = valueB[type]();
    obj.propC = valueC[type]();
}
```

Comment: Still quite repeating :)

Answer (score 1):

@HarshvardhanSharma, due to the lack of a pattern among properties calculation, I've reused as much as possible. Plus, used array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to exclude the passed type and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to make the calculation only over the siblings. **The proposed solution it's a bit more verbose, but clear to understand and update. Hope it helps**.

```js
var obj = {
  propA: 1,
  propB: 2,
  propC: 0.5, 
};

function updateObjV2({type, val, modifierA, modifierB}) {
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => key !== `prop${type}`)
    .forEach(key => {
      // Reuse conditions with consts
      const isPropA = key === 'propA';
      const isPropB = key === 'propB';
      const isPropC = key === 'propC';
      const isTypeA = type === 'A';
      const isTypeB = type === 'B';
      const isTypeC = type === 'C';
      
      switch(true) {
        case isPropA && isTypeB:
        case isPropB && isTypeA:
          obj[key] = val / modifierB * modifierA;
          break;
          
        case isPropA && isTypeC:
        case isPropB && isTypeC:
          obj[key] = val / modifierB * 100;
          break;
          
        case isPropC && isTypeA:
          obj[key] = val / 100 * modifierA;
          break;
          
        case isPropC && isTypeB:
          obj[key] = val / 100 * modifierB; 
          break;
      }
      
    });
}

console.log('BEFORE - Type A was passed ::', obj);
updateObjV2({ type: 'A', val: 5, modifierA: 12, modifierB: 20});
console.log('AFTER - Type A was passed ::', obj);
```